# Smallest of 3 Integers and Prints the Smallest Numerically in the Group

Tags: c++, cout

I wrote my first program in C++ which reads in three integers and determines which is the smallest number from the group. However I need some guidance on how to prompt the user and read the three values from the console with a `cout` print message.

In my pseudo code I have it to be...""The smallest value among `a, b, and c is x` (where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `x` are replaced by the actual values.)

I am just stuck on how to implement that with my code.

My requirements are:

- Comparison operators, `&&` and `||`
- Else and nesting allowed

Any guidance is really appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cout << "Enter the value of a: ";
        cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the value of b: ";
        cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter the value of c: ";
        cin >> c;

   if (a < b)
        d = a;
    else
        d = b;

        cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " << ((d < c) ? d : c) << endl; //


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you want help with the prompting and input (which already work) or with the output?

Comment: `int smallest = std::min(a, std::min(b, c));`

Comment: The output was mainly what I was struggling with however after reviewing the comments below. I see what I was not doing.

Comment: If any of those answers your question then you might want to choose one as "accepted answer", it's a way of saying "thank you" C:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the message `The smallest value among a, b, c` then this is what you need

```
int a, b, c, d;
cout << "Enter the value of a: ";
    cin >> a;
cout << "Enter the value of b: ";
    cin >> b;
cout << "Enter the value of c: ";
    cin >> c;

if(a < b && b < c) {
    d = a;
}
else {
    if(b < a && b < c) {
        d = b;
    }
    else {
        d = c;
    }
}

cout << "the smallest value among " << a << ", " << b << " and " << c << " is: " << d << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking input is correct, after taking input:

```
if(a<b){
  if(a<c){
    cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " <<a<<endl;
  }
  else{
    cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " <<c<<endl;
  }
}
else {
 if(b<c){
    cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " <<b<<endl;
  }
 else{
    cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " <<c<<endl;
  }
}
```

You can do it in one line:

```
d = a<b? (a<c?a:c) : (b<c?b:c);
cout << "the smallest of the numbers is: " <<d<<endl;
```